# Preserve of database connection in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

currently i create a ASP.NET WebApi application. Due to RESTful Applications are Session-Stateless i am thinking about how to preserve a open database connection? I also could reopen the database everytime a user sends a WebApi request.

But which solution would be the better one?

1. Try to preserve the database connection - but how?
2. Re-Open the connection everytime a user sends a WebApi request?

Thanks, Andreas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should keep the connection open as little as possible. Close the connection right after you finished using it. Connection Pooling in .NET will handle physical connections to DB for you so you don't have to worry about performance. You will actually impact performance by keeping open connections for a long period of time.

Comment: But then there are properply many database connections open at the same time. This is also no problem in .NET?

Comment: No. .NET connections you're working with are NOT physical connections to database. .NET Framework handles them for you.